# Bypass "trying to get property of non-object" error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My objective is to handle these error. I know that this error is produced when the query return is null.

I get `trying to get property of non-object` error by using the code below.

```
foreach($furniture as $fur)
{
  Furniture Name: {{$fur->fur_name}}
  Furniture Country : {{ App\Country::where('id', $fur->country_id)->first()->country_name }}
}
```

After a bit of research on the internet, I use this code below but still not successful, the error still persist.

```
foreach($furniture as $fur)
{
  Furniture Name: $fur->fur_name
  Furniture Country : {{ App\Country::where('id', $fur->country_id)->first()->country_name ? App\Country::where('id', $fur->country_id)->first()->country_name : "null/no record"}}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
foreach($furniture as $fur)
{
  Furniture Name: $fur->fur_name
  Furniture Country : {{ App\Country::where('id', $fur->country_id)->first() ? App\Country::where('id', $fur->country_id)->first()->country_name : "null/no record"}}
}
```

It's not recommended running queries from your views directly. Instead, move the query into a controller and pass the result to the view.

Comment: Straight forward solution, this is exactly what i'm looking for. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach (needs php 7.*):

```
foreach($furniture as $fur)
{
  Furniture Name: $fur->fur_name
  Furniture Country : {{ App\Country::where('id', $fur->country_id)->first()->country_name ?? "No record" }}
}
```

**??** is a **null coalescing operator** for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with isset().

Just take note as @Camilo said, It's not recommended running queries from your views directly instead relocate it in your controller and only pass **result** in your view.